# Workflow email latest document in library

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online

I have a custom content type that is a excel spreadsheet. Users access this to create quote requests. At the moment, when a new request is saved to the library, an email is sent telling an admin user a new request exists. However, it doesn't reference the document or a hyperlink of some variety.

How can I get the workflow to send the email containing either the name of the document, or a link directly to it (ideally, both).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a workflow to handle this. Instead of the alert, just trigger the workflow anytime an new item is added you would email a specific user and add the parameters for a hyperlink as well as document name. This is really easy to build in SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Any pointers, I can't tell entirely what lookups I would require to build an entire link to the doc?

Comment: Here is a post of the Office365 community that breaks down creating an Item URL well. http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/245002.aspx

Comment: Here is another one that you can use to build custom HTML email templates from my blog as well. I was building a table in that post, but the steps would be the same if you wanted to dress it up at all. https://benjooster.wordpress.com/2014/07/15/create-reusable-html-emails-in-sharepoint-designer/